# How to update value if one of the field has multiple same values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database table, one of the fields has the same values. I want to change this value with random number or string which is appended to this field value for uniqueness.

Sample Data
Here `'Ma' has 5 records` and so on. I want to change Name `Ma01, Ma02` etc.

```
Id  Name  Count
1   Ma   5
2   Ga   6
3   Gu   5
```

How can do with `SQL` query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE TBL
SET Name = A.Name
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        Name + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NVARCHAR(500)) AS NAME,
        Count
    FROM
        TBL
    WHERE
        NAME IN 
        (
            SELECT T.NAME FROM TBL T
            GROUP BY T.NAME
            HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
        )

) A
WHERE
    TBL.Id = A.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select Name + convert(varchar(2), row_number()over(partition by Name order by Name))
From tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

You just try this.

```
Declare @i int  = 1

update yourtable
set ID  = @i , @i = @i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Code based on NEER`s code with leading zero added, tested on MSSQL database.

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Name,
    Name + RIGHT('00'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY (SELECT Name)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),2) AS Updatedname

FROM
    tablename
WHERE
    Name IN 
    (
        SELECT T.NameFROM tablename T
        GROUP BY T.Name
        HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1
    )
GROUP BY Name,Id
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: please give sample to understand more clear, because you are given your column.

Comment: I have updated the code for you with the same column names as you used. just replace the tablename value with your own table